# How does pyglet know how to run the on_draw() function?

Tags: python, pyglet

Here's a quick python sample code using pyglet:

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window()
image = pyglet.resource.image('kitten.jpg')

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    image.blit(0, 0)

pyglet.app.run()
```

I understand that `@window.event` is a decorator and the function `on_draw()` is modified by it. What I don't understand is how running `pyglet.app.run()` knows about this new draw function, so it can run it.

Comment: Presumably, `@window.event` also registers this function somehow so that the `window` object has a reference to it and knows when to call it.

Comment: @ForceBru oh, got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The @window.event runs functions based on certain events (like on_mouse_press, on_key_press, etc.), and the on_draw event is just triggered once every frame.